# How to create nested class object to be serialized for API call using HttpClient in C#

Tags: c#, json, post, serialization, httpclient

Essentially I am attempting to make an POST call using HttpClient (no wiggle room here, has to be HttpClient). I also

```
POST SOMEURL
--header 'Content-Type: application/json \
--data-raw '{
    “itemData”: {
        “Name”: “Finance_GiftCardServiceFee”,
        “Priority”: “Normal”,
        “SpecificContent”: {
            “Type”: "Card Number”,
            “Name@odata.type”: “#String”,
            “Name”: “WRITE OUT CARD NUMBER”
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I am currently attempting to make the call (this call occurs after a token has been secured)

```
 private void callAPI1()
        {
           Dictionary<string, string> testDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            testDictionary.Add("Type", "Card Number");
            testDictionary.Add("Name@odata.type", "#String");
            testDictionary.Add("Name", "1234567");

            ItemData itemData = new ItemData { Name = "Finance_GiftCardServiceFee", Priority = "Normal", SpecificContent = testDictionary };

           request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, RELATIVEPATH);
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);


           stream = new MemoryStream();
           jsonSer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ItemData));
           jsonSer.WriteObject(stream, itemData);
           stream.Position = 0;
           sr = new StreamReader(stream);
           body = sr.ReadToEnd();

           request.Content = new StringContent(body,
                                      Encoding.UTF8,
                                      "application/json");

           response = client.Send(request);
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS");
           }
        }
            

        public class ItemData
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string Priority { get; set; }

            public Dictionary<string, string> SpecificContent { get; set; }
        }
```

This was my best guess in figuring out how to get it to serialize, but I keep getting the following: "StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'"

Now, I am able to switch out the "body" variable with the following and have it work, but, as I stated earlier, it has to be in class format.

```
body = @"{
                    " + "\n" +
                    @"  ""itemData"": {
                    " + "\n" +
                    @"    ""Name"": ""Finance_GiftCardServiceFee"",
                    " + "\n" +
                    @"    ""Priority"": ""Normal"",
                    " + "\n" +
                    @"    ""SpecificContent"": {
                    " + "\n" +
                    @"""Card Number"":""12334567""
                    " + "\n" +
                    @"}
                    " + "\n" +
                    @"  }
                    " + "\n" +
                    @"}";
```

Any and all help and suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: You are serializing an instance of `ItemData` as the body of the request, but your example clearly shows that the JSON should include an outer object that has an `itemData` property -- that part doesn't exist in your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

to create the json you created manually, your class should be

```
public class Data
{
    public ItemData ItemData {get; set;}
}
public class ItemData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Priority { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> SpecificContent { get; set; }
}
```

and to send this class object try this code

```
Dictionary<string, string> testDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    testDictionary.Add("Type", "Card Number");
    testDictionary.Add("Name@odata.type", "#String");
    testDictionary.Add("Name", "1234567");

    Data data = new Data
    {
        ItemData = new ItemData
        {
            Name = "Finance_GiftCardServiceFee",
            Priority = "Normal",
            SpecificContent = testDictionary
        }
    };

var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


     var baseUri= @"http://localhost:55480";
      var uri = "api/testapi/postjson";
    
    
    using HttpClient client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri) };
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
    
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(stringData);
    }
```

body content

```
{
  "ItemData": {
    "Name": "Finance_GiftCardServiceFee",
    "Priority": "Normal",
    "SpecificContent": {
      "Type": "Card Number",
      "Name@odata.type": "#String",
      "Name": "1234567"
    }
  }
}
```